# How to separate elements of a 2-d string in python?

Tags: python, list

How do I make a 2-d list into a format where each 1-d list is put in a new line? For example, if I had a 2-d list with integers like:

`alist = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`

Without using NumPy, how do you change it into a format like:

`[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6] [7, 8, 9, 10]`

I apologize for my bad description, I am a still quite new to python and help would be greatly appreciated

I tried using for loops like
`for i in range(len(alist)):      for j in range(len(alist[I])):         print(a[i][j], end=' ')`

But the results I have gotten dont seem to follow the format.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark While they said "each 1-d list is put in a new line" they also explicitly showed the output `[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6] [7, 8, 9, 10]` as one line, even written like that in the markdown. Not up to us to decide which one they actually want.

Comment: @KellyBundy Fair enough. OP, could you edit the post to clarify the intent here?

Comment: Possible duplicate (once the output is clarified): [Printing list elements on separate lines](/q/6167731/4518341). Note that the top answer (`"\n".join()`) only works on strings, so use [this answer](/a/6168360/4518341) (`print(*alist, sep='\n')`) or [this answer](/a/6168004/4518341) (`for sublist in alist: print(sublist)`) instead.

Comment: @Kelly The new Ask Question wizard exposes kinda confusing behaviour for code formatting, so it should be safe to assume OP meant what they said but messed up the formatting. For some context, [here's a vaguely similar bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416801/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea So that wizard combines such lines entered as separate lines into a single line? Hard to believe. And I don't think that assumption is safe.

Comment: @Kelly Believe it, it's buggy as hell :| I can reproduce the problem by pasting the multiline text, selecting it with the mouse (not Ctrl+A, weirdly), clicking **Inline code**, then toggling off **Markdown**. That said, erring on the side of caution is fine by me.

Comment: @wjandrea Well, clicking **inline** code is your mistake, but yeah, the editor should then probably better also make it one line in the markdown.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to separate them onto different lines:

```py
for sublist in alist:
    print(sublist)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `'\n'.join()`, as suggested by [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx):

```py
print('\n'.join(str(sublist) for sublist in alist))
```

If you want them to be all on the same line, use `' '.join()` rather than `'\n'.join()`:

```py
print(' '.join(str(sublist) for sublist in alist))
```

---

Additionally, you can use the unpacking operator when calling `print()`, as pointed out by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea):

```py
print(*alist, sep='\n')
```

Comment: You can also use `'\n'.join(...)` instead of `' '.join()` for laying them out onto multiple lines.

Comment: Added with attribution. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `print('\n'.join(str ...))`, you can have `print` do the heavy lifting: `print(*alist, sep='\n')`

Comment: Also added with attribution!